# JSP form passing values to using post

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

OK so I'm trying to pass values from a form on a page.

**contact.jsp**

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="confirm.jsp">
                   <p> Cell Line: <input type="text"  name="cell" />
                   <p> Tissue Source<input type="text"  name="source" />
                   <p> Temperature: <input type="text"  name="temp" />
                   <p> Run-Time: <input type='text'   name='run' />
                  <input type="submit" value="Request!"onclick="window.location.href='confirm.jsp'" />
/form>
```

**confirm.jsp**

```
<div class="controls">
<p><label>Cell Line:</label> <% String cell=request.getParameter("cell"); out.println(cell); %> </p>
<p><label>Tissue Source:</label> <% String source=request.getParameter("source"); out.println(source); %> </p>
<p><label>Temperature:</label> <% String temp=request.getParameter("temp"); out.println(temp); %> </p>
<p><label>Run-Time</label> <% String run=request.getParameter("first"); out.println(run); %> </p>
<p class="help-block"></p>
</div>
```

I'm passing these values to confirm.jsp. what have I done wrong here? Do i need to set a servlet in my web.xml. everything on the inter webs points me to this code, but to date all i get is null values.

Any help would be great

Comment: In you text fields have you entered any value and then clicked on submit button?

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
 <input type="submit" value="Request!"onclick="window.location.href='confirm.jsp'" />
```

Use

```
<input type="submit" value="Request!"/>
```

There is no need of configuring in `web.xml` file. Since in `form` tag you wrote `action="confirm.jsp`.

Comment: hmm... the button doesn't take me anywhere now, and the values are still null if I manually enter the URL.

Comment: If  your `form` code in some other `jsp`. It will works. @Rocky

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: i wrote this in a page called contact.jsp i am trying to access the information on confirm.jsp

Comment: ... i mean it doesn't but ty anyway

Comment: Other than this I didn't find any other issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**contact.jsp**

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="confirm.jsp">
                   <p> Cell Line: <input type="text"  name="cell" />
                   <p> Tissue Source<input type="text"  name="source" />
                   <p> Temperature: <input type="text"  name="temp" />
                   <p> Run-Time: <input type='text'   name='run' />
                  <input type="submit" value="Request!" />
/form>
```

**confirm.jsp**

```
<div class="controls">
<p><label>Cell Line:</label> <% String cell=request.getParameter("cell"); out.println(cell); %> </p>
<p><label>Tissue Source:</label> <% String source=request.getParameter("source"); out.println(source); %> </p>
<p><label>Temperature:</label> <% String temp=request.getParameter("temp"); out.println(temp); %> </p>
<p><label>Run-Time</label> <% String run=request.getParameter("first"); out.println(run); %> </p>
<p class="help-block"></p>
</div>
```

that woks for me so fine !!